# Unable to register Google Play - Developer console

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

Are we able to be both user of a developer account and owner of a developer console ?

The fact is that my personal Google address is linked to a developer console for my work and I wanted to create my own developer console to publish my personal apps.

Unfortunately, I got the error below while creating my own developer console on Google Play Services. I look for leaving the other account but I wasn't able to find anything like this.

[image: Google Play Registration Error]

> Oh oh ! An error occurred. An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry later.

If possible, I don't want to create a new account but unlink my personal account from my work developer console.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you solved your own question always add an answer with the solution and accept it so your question will not remain unanswered.

Comment: @Luksprog I'm not allowed to add an answer on my own question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at network requests, I saw a request going to Google Payments Services which end to a 500 error. At this moment, I just remember that I've conflict with my Google Payments account. When I solved it, I was totally able to be both member of a Developer Console and owner of my own Developer Console. On the Developer Console UI, I'm able to switch between the 2 accounts thanks to the menu on top right corner.